# How to annotate with dotted black lines and numbers on marginal univariate plots in seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Here is my code:

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

sns.set(style="ticks", color_codes=True)

g = sns.JointGrid(x="total_bill", y="tip", data=tips)

g.plot_joint(sns.regplot, line_kws={"color": "coral"}, scatter_kws={"color": "gray"})
plt.grid()
rsquare = lambda a, b: stats.pearsonr(a, b)[0] ** 2
g = g.annotate(rsquare, template="{stat}: {val:.2f}", stat="$R^2$", loc="upper left", fontsize=12)

g = g.plot_marginals(sns.kdeplot, color="steelblue", shade=True, linewidth=3)

marg_x = g.ax_marg_x
marg_y = g.ax_marg_y
marg_x.annotate('15', xy=(15, 0), xytext=(15, 1), arrowprops=dict(facecolor='k', arrowstyle='-' ))
marg_x.annotate('25', xy=(25, 0), xytext=(25, 1), arrowprops=dict(facecolor='k', arrowstyle='-' ))
marg_y.annotate('2', xy=(0, 2),xytext=(1, 2), arrowprops=dict(facecolor='k', arrowstyle='-' ))
marg_y.annotate('4', xy=(0, 4),xytext=(1, 4), arrowprops=dict(facecolor='k', arrowstyle='-' ))

plt.show()
```

As we can see from the code, I would like to annotate both marg_x and marg_y with black lines, but it seems that marg_x and marg_y have been annotated by  white lines, and the numbers('15','25','2','4') doesn't show up at all. In addition, I prefer to dotted line. How should I annotate?

PS:When I ran the code, I got a warning as follow:

> D:\pycharm\PyCharm 2018.3\helpers\pycharm_matplotlib_backend\backend_interagg.py:62: UserWarning: Tight layout not applied. The bottom and top margins cannot be made large enough to accommodate all axes decorations. 
>     self.figure.tight_layout() 
>   Does this warning relate to my problems?

Comment: Mind that for the y-margin, the data needs to be in the y-coordinate (x is horizontal, y is vertical axis).

Comment: Thank you for answering! I changed the code, and I can annotate both marg_x and marg_y now. Could you please teach me how to make the numbers show up and annotate with balck dotted lines?

Answer (score 0):

I found that there is an easy way，that is to use Axes.plot. In fact that was the first answer came into my mind, but at the time I set the wrong parameters, so I switched to Axes.annotate. Following is the final code.

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

sns.set(style="ticks", color_codes=True)

g = sns.JointGrid(x="total_bill", y="tip", data=tips)

g.plot_joint(sns.regplot, line_kws={"color": "coral"}, scatter_kws={"color": "gray"})
plt.grid()
rsquare = lambda a, b: stats.pearsonr(a, b)[0] ** 2
g = g.annotate(rsquare, template="{stat}: {val:.2f}", stat="$R^2$", loc="upper left", fontsize=12)

g = g.plot_marginals(sns.kdeplot, color="steelblue", shade=True, linewidth=3)

marg_x = g.ax_marg_x
marg_y = g.ax_marg_y
x = [2,2]
y = [0,0.05]
marg_x.plot(x,y,'k--')

x = [4,4]
y = [0,0.05]
marg_x.plot(x,y,'k--')


y = [4,4]
x = [0,0.4]
marg_y.plot(x,y,'k--')

y = [7,7]
x = [0,0.4]
marg_y.plot(x,y,'k--')

plt.show()
```